# REST API Specification Location?

Tags: artifactory

I'm attempting to get a clear view of the current state of the REST API in a deployed Artifactory Server in v6.x, primarily to auto-generate a javascript SDK.

Previously the REST API had a WADL file hosted at http://:/artifactory/api/application.wadl but it appears this has been removed as of v6 (v5 documentation shows it https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF5X/Artifactory+REST+API) but this is missing as of the v6 documentation.

Does anyone know if the specification for the API is available anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the WADL file is no longer available to be downloaded through JFrog Artifactory. The complete documentation for the REST API is available in [the documentation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API) though.